# How to connect Azure Bizspark from another PC?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, bizspark

I'm trying to connect to azure bizspark from another PC. But its not able to recognize the azure bizspark VM (xxxx.cloudapp.com)? Am I missing something? Is it possible to copy csv files and send to azure bizspark through any programming or bat?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to connect to an Azure VM is to download a Remote Desktop Protocol file:

1. Sign in to the Azure portal.
2. Click Virtual Machines.
3. Select the virtual machine from the list.
4. On the page for the virtual machine, click Connect.
5. Download the Remote Desktop Protocol file (.rdp file) and click Open.

Like in the Azure Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/connect-logon

Azure Bizspark it's a Microsoft program for Startups https://bizspark.microsoft.com/. This doesn't matter, the resources are the same that in a normal Azure account.

Comment: I tried downloading rdp and I'm not able to log in. And when I tried pinging it didnt work. Does it mean the VM is not setup properly?

Comment: Do you get some error message? Please try to add information if not it's really difficult to try to help you.